# Is there a way to make an if condition to ignore certain lines in a script?

Tags: python, if-statement, exception

Is there a way to make an if condition to ignore certain lines of code? Here is part of my script, which calculates various things concerning matrices:

```
choice=raw_input("What do you wish to do?(sum/sub/mult/scal/det/trace/transp/cofac/adjointa/inv)")


o =raw_input("Enter dimensions of matrix 1(Ej.:3x4, where 3 is the number of rows and for the number of columns)" " ")
r=raw_input("Enter dimensions of matrix 2" " ")
X=[i for i in o]
Y=[i for i in r]
n,m,p,q=int(X[0]),int(X[2]),int(Y[0]),int(Y[2])

rowsofmatrix1,rowsofmatrix2= {},{}

for i in range (1,n+1):
    while True:
        a=raw_input("Enter row " " " +str(i)+ " " " of the first matrix with each row separated with a space" " ")
        M=split(a)
        if len(M)!=m:
            print "should enter a file of" " "+str(m)+" " "numbers"
            continue
        else:
            break
    M=[float(x) for x in M]
    indexcorrection={}

    for h in range(1,m+1):
        indexcorrection[h]=M[h-1]
    rowsofmatrix1[i]=indexcorrection

for j in range (1,p+1):
    while True:
        b=raw_input("Enter row " " " +str(j)+ " " "of the second matrix with each row separated with a space" " ")
        Q=split(b)
        if len(Q)!=q:
            print "should enter a row with" " "+str(q)+" " "numbers"
            continue
        else:
            break
    Q=[float(x) for x in Q]
    indexcorrection={}
    for h in range(1,q+1):
        indexcorrection[h]=Q[h-1]
    rowsofmatrix2[j]=indexcorrection
```

So, as you might know, the determinant is a function of just one matrix, as is the trace or the inverse. In change, adding,substracting and multiplying matrices is a function of two matrices. So, I don't wish to ask the user for the entries of the second matrix when he asks, for example, the determinant. Also, I don't want to ask for the dimension of the second matrix.
My question is then: can I do an if statment like:

```
if choice!=='sum' and choice!=='mult' and choice!='sub': 
     Ignore the whole block which asks for rows of the second matrix. 
     Ignore line which asks dimension of the second matrix
     Ignore the lines which split dimensions of the second matrix
```

Comment: If conditions already skip sections of code. Please show an example of what you want

Comment: You could also extract portions of the code into functions.

Comment: if you don't yet want to create code for some `if/elif` code blocks you can fill them with `pass` (behaves like a "skip")

Comment: Now I think it's better

Comment: you'd want to do as cricket mentioned in the second comment, put those blocks of code you conditionally want not to run into functions, and only call them when you *do* want to use them